# take values from two tables and store result in third table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. First is with users and second with orders so i want to choose both values and save the result in third table. I created two drop down lists so far.

```
 <select id="select1">
    <option disabled selected>-- Select User --</option>
    <?php
        include "config.php";  
        $records = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT username From users");  

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['username'] ."'>" .$data['username'] ."</option>";  
        }   
    ?>  
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option disabled selected>-- Select order --</option>
    <?php
        include "config.php";  
        $records = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name From orders");  

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {
            echo "<option value='". $data['name'] ."'>" .$data['name'] ."</option>";  
        }   
    ?>  
  </select>
```

I want to ask how could I create third table in database with results taken from users and orders? Or should I do it another way?
I'd like to have result like:

```
Name | Order
John | Repair car
```

Comment: If you specifically need to store the information in a third table, surely it would be simply a case of adding an `INSERT` query once you have retrieved the data. However, why do you need to combine the data into another table? It is very rarely a good idea to duplicate data. Presumably your `orders` table contains a reference to the `users` table, in which case you can combine the data whenever you need to without duplicating it into a another table.

Comment: You've got a confusing set of column names. In `users` you have `username`, which is fine, but in `orders` you have `name`, not `ordername`. Then in your result you call the `username` column `Name` and the `name` column `Order`. Confusion is complete.

Comment: I want to save the result in another table because after I take the results i want to show these results at site

Comment: I think you need to create an extra column in your `orders` table that refers to the user to whom the order belongs. No third table needed. That is, as long as one order is always associated with one user.

Comment: Yes, it is always associated with only one user.

Comment: so I manually created table named assigned_orders in my database because it's easier for me and i created a button 

```<input type="submit" name="getOption" value="getOption" onclick="getOption()" />```
and I am trying to insert data from users and orders into assigned_orders:
```if(isset($_POST['getOption']))
{
  $result=mysqli_query($link, "
   INSERT INTO assigned_others (username, ordername) SELECT username, ordername from users, orders ")
 ?> ```
and there is an error "unexpected end of file"

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins. Add to your 'orders' table the user id and in your sql query make a join

table users

```
id
username
address
city
...
```

table orders

```
id
user_id
name
product
price....
```

SQL

```
SELECT u.username, u.address, o.name, o.price...
FROM users u
INNER JOIN orders o
ON u.id = o.user_id
WHERE (yours conditions)
```

Comment: but while I want to take values chosen in dropdown list like User and Order are u sure it will work because i can't see connection between these chosen values from dropdown lists or am i wrong?